# Performance graph example

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to build a performance widget using `Qt` to display the download progress, cpu/ram usage etc. I want something like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Should I use the `QGraphicsScene` or `QSplineSeries` with `QChart` to achieve it? Any ideas how to create such widget? Thanks.

Comment: use  QCustomPlot  https://www.qcustomplot.com/

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan

Ok. I will check it. Thanks.